# Java Eclipse Source Not Found but can CTRL-click into Method

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to debug the application. I am hitting a Source Not Found error and there is a button to click on Edit Source Lookup Path. I have tried specifying the source file directory but it still won't debug into it.

I can CTRL-click into the source code file in Eclipse Editor but why in debug mode I am unable to single step into it?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This happens for me, because there are two version of the source on the classpath.
Right click on debug stacktrace (on Debug tab) -> Edit source Lookup Path -> click search for duplicate source files on the path checkbox. After that try to open an editor again for the source and if it asks you which version do you want to load, load the class file.